# Check if input has focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input with a minimum number of characters required. When a user start typing something and then switch to another field without reaching the minimum number of characters required, I want to change the class of a text to turn it to red.

I have tried using this code to detect when the focus change but it is not working:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $('#job_desc').is(':active');
}, function(){
    console.log('test');
})
```

what is the problem?

Many thanks

Comment: did you additionally add jquery to your angular project or rely on angular's jquery-lite (by default)?

Comment: i have jquery as well

Comment: why don't you bind the blur event on the required form elements? `$('.blurrable').bind('blur', function(evt) { ... });` and if you need to recalculate it, you could do a scope.$apply() within the blur event callback.

Comment: The watch isn't really an event handler and won't be evaluated until the next digest cycle. Use ngBlur and ngFocus to detect focus changes. Better yet, look into angular validations, which is meant for this exact scenario here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using angularjs 1.2 you have two directives to help you to watch if a field has focus: ng-focus and ng-blur. If not, it's quite simple to implement your own directives. The code [(plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/E97OSfd8C3DLYpRabrMF?p=preview):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
       <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <form>
       <input ng-model="name" id="name" ng-focus="focused()" ng-blur="blurred()">
       <input ng-model="name2">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

and the javascript

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.focused = function() {
    console.log("got focus");
  }

   $scope.blurred = function() {
    console.log("lost focus");
  }
});
```

If on the other hand, you just want validation, look into form validation in angularjs, something like myForm.myInput.$valid. Angularjs sets the ng-valid and ng-invalid classes accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen by specific selector also, like this.

```
function listenForFocus() {
    var el = angular.element( document.querySelectorAll( 'input, select' ) );
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        var element = angular.element(el[i]);
        element.bind('blur', function (e) {
            console.log('blur');
        });
        element.bind('focus', function (e) {
            console.log('focus');
        });
    }
}
```